# Why is my search box positioned differently in IE and Chrome?

Tags: css, firefox, forms, google-chrome, input

please take a look at my site here: http://utilitiessavings.co.uk

The search box at the top-right, in the nav bar is positioned differently in chrome and FF. I can't seem to find a way to change it to make it consistent. Obviously I want it to look like it does in ff in all browsers.

I expect this in IE, but not these two!

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like some stray styles applied some padding to the form holding the textbox.

Comment: Apologoes for the title, it should read "Firefox and Chrome". I guess it was just a freudian slip as i'm so used to things in IE being the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To this input

```
body.custom li form input {}
```

add

```
margin:0;
```

Altough chrome sets some user agent style as `margin:0em` seems like that doesn't affect the input.

Comment: Thanks so much! That would have annoyed me so much otherwise!